# unable to route the http requests to the web application in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a reactjs application running at port 5000. I want to route the requests from nginx to the webapp.

I am getting the below log

```
2019/06/20 04:30:10 [error] 17709#17709: *67 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 72.163.217.106, server: 159.65.123.84, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: “example.com”
2019/06/20 04:30:10 [error] 17709#17709: *69 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 72.163.217.106, server: 159.65.123.84, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/favicon.ico", host: “example.com”, referrer: "http://example.com/“
2019/06/20 04:30:10 [error] 17709#17709: *71 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 72.163.217.106, server: 159.65.123.84, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/favicon.ico", host: “example.com”, referrer: "http://example.com/“
```

Here are my nginx config file at **/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name example.com; # or server_name subdomain.yourapp.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        # Enables WS support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

what could be the reason for this kind of behavior. How to fix this issue.

Comment: 5000 is not 8000.

Comment: Its a typo i am sorry. I have 5000 in the configs.

Comment: OK, what is in the error log?

Comment: i posted my error log in the question.failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream,

Comment: Those messages don't make sense in this context. They contain port 8000, but you said you made a typo. Fix the typo, then try again and check for new error log messages.

Comment: Hi Michael, I got the issue now the configs are not getting updated by nginx. even though i mentioned 5000 in the configs nginx is routing to 8000.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95167/discussion-between-wandermonk-and-michael-hampton).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are passing the requests to port 8000 in your nginx configuration. Try passing them to port 5000 because as per your post your ReactJS app is running on port 5000.